# Change default locale in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to change the default locale of my application. Things I've tried so far:

- set intl.default_locale to 'et_EE'
- set locale to 'et' in `app/config/parameters.ini`
- Changed the default locale in my bundle's boot() method described [here](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/5bc1b890624982b1)
- Implemented a class Locale that extends StubLocale and overwrites method getDefault() to return 'et_EE'.

Here is the implementation. The Locale class does not seem to be getting overwritten as calling `\Locale::getDefault()` doesn't execute this method.

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Locale\Stub\StubLocale;

class Locale extends StubLocale
{
    static public function getDefault()
    {
        return 'et_EE';
    }
}
```

After trying all these methods described, `\Locale::getDefault()` still returns `en`. I need it to return `et_EE` to render form widgets, such as country or language, in the proper locale.

How would I go doing this? Being able to support multiple locales later would also be great. Thanks.

Comment: \Locale::getDefault() won't execute this method, as it's provided by the PHP. The Locale class being used by Symfony is not \Locale, rather than \Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale which extends the \Locale.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Symfony 2.0:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
  session: { default_locale: en }
```

In Symfony 2.1+:

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
  default_locale: en
```

Comment: Kudos! I skimmed that place over many times and since it had     session: { default_locale: %locale% } I assumed it took the value from parameters.ini. It works.

Comment: this is outdated. its now a setting of the framework config: `framework:
    default_locale: %locale%`

Answer (score 6):

In Symfony 2.0, you can set `default_locale` for the session too:

```
framework:
  translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
  ...
  session:
    default_locale: %locale%
    auto_start:     true
```

The `%locale%` is a variable, and it's resolved from the `parameters.ini` file.